# Move navigations into header part and do not disturb the responsive mobile screen

Tags: magento2, header, navigation

My original theme screen is like this[image]

But I want in this way[image]

But due to these changes, my responsive view gets distorted like this[image].

I wrote this line of code in the default.xml file `<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly use this one:

`<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />`

Comment: Thanks Dotsquares, it worked for me.